# Homework issues. Trouble writing methods for a calendar appointment program

Tags: java, methods, calendar, appointment

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Class Day: This class is used to represent one day of a schedule. The data is
 * an array of boolean values that represent whether an appointment is scheduled
 * for a particular hour of the day. There is also a description that is
 * associated with each hour of the day - saved in an array of Strings.
 *
 * Last Modified: [10FEB2020]
 * Author: [Adam Vieth]
 */

public class Day extends HandleInput {
    // Attributes

    // There are 24 hours in a day, so this
    // array should have 24 elements. If an
    // element is true, that means an appointment
    // is scheduled during that hour. If it is
    // false, then there is no appointment scheduled
    // during that hour.
    private boolean[] isBusy;

    // This also should have 24 elements, one
    // for each hour of the day. If an appointment
    // is scheduled for an hour, then this array
    // should hold a String description of the
    // appointment.
    private String[] appointmentDescription;

    /**
     * Constructor for the Day class. This should allocate memory for the attribute
     * arrays, and should initialize each hour to have no appointments.
     * 
     */
    public Day() 
    {
         isBusy = new boolean[24];
         appointmentDescription = new String[24];   
    }

    /**
     * This method should return whether or not there is an appointment scheduled
     * for a particular time of this day.
     *
     * @param hour
     *            The hour during this day whose status is being checked.
     * @return true if there is an appointment scheduled during the requested hour,
     *         false if there is not.
     */
    public boolean checkTime(int hour) {
        if(isBusy[hour] == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method should return whether or not there is an appointment scheduled at
     * any hour of this day.
     *
     * @return true if there is an appointment scheduled during any hour of this
     *         day, false if there are no appointments for this entire day.
     */

    public boolean checkDay() 
    {   

        for(int i = 0; i < isBusy.length; i++)
        {
            if(isBusy[i] == false)
            {
                return true;
            }       
        }
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * This method should return the appointment description for the appointment at
     * the given time of this day.
     *
     * @param hour
     *            The hour during this day whose appointment description should be
     *            returned.
     * @return If an appointment is scheduled at the given hour, then the
     *         appointment description should be returned, otherwise the text "No
     *         appointment scheduled" should be returned.
     */
    public String getDescription(int hour) 
    {
        if(isBusy[hour] == true)
        {
            return appointmentDescription[hour];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method should add a new appointment to the given hour for this day. This
     * method should modify the isBusy and appointmentDescription for the given day
     * only if there is not already an appointment for the given hour.
     *
     * @param hour
     *            The hour during this day for which an appointment should be made.
     * @param description
     *            The text description of the new appointment.
     * @return false if there is already an appointment scheduled during the given
     *         hour (the previous appointment information should not be modified),
     *         and true if adding the appointment was successful (there was no
     *         previous appointment).
     */
    public boolean addAppointment(int hour, String description) {

        if(isBusy[hour] == false)
        {
            appointmentDescription[hour] = description;
            isBusy[hour] = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }       
    }

    /**
     * This method should remove an appointment for a given hour for this day. There
     * should be no effect if there was not an appointment scheduled in the first
     * place.
     *
     * @param hour
     *            The hour during this day for which an appointment removed.
     */
    public void removeAppointment(int hour) {
        if(isBusy[hour] == true)
        {
            isBusy[hour] = false;
            appointmentDescription[hour] = null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method should generate a String of all appointment times and
     * descriptions for a given hour for this day. There should be no print
     * statements in this method, only the code to create a String.
     *
     * @return A String whose text is one line for each appointment on this day.
     *         Each line should have the appointment time and the appointment
     *         description. See the program description for the exact formatting.
     */
    public String toString() {
        /* TODO - write this method */
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < isBusy.length; i++)
        {
            if(appointmentDescription[i] == null)
            {
                return "No appointments scheduled for this entire day"; 
            }
            if(appointmentDescription[i] != null)
            {
                output = appointmentDescription[i];
            }

        }
        return output;
}
}
```

Currently I am having a hand full of issues with this program. I feel like some of the methods I have written are not working right. I am especially having issues writing the toString() method. This should return a list of all the appointments I have in a given day when the program is running. 
I am newer to java and am having trouble getting the hang of this. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `output = appointmentDescription[i];` overwrites the entirety of `output`, so when `output` is returned, it will only contain the description of the last appointment. You probably want to add to `output` like this rather than overwriting it: `output = output + appointmentDescription[i];`

Comment: Also Stack Overflow is tailored more towards solutions for specific bugs. You may be able to get more constructive, general feedback over on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Good luck :)

Comment: I noticed as well, you have a `return` statement in your code block that checks if an appointment in the day is null. Once this is reached, the function stops executing entirely, so in this case if any hour has a null `appointmentDescription` entry, the function will immediately stop executing. You may want to append that message to `output` rather than `return`ing it so all appointments can be processed before anything is returned.

Comment: As a comment to your two arrays: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections | Jon Skeet's coding blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Comment: @HewwoCraziness Code review is for working code. Please don't recommend questions which are off-topic for Code Review. And/Or direct new users to the FAQ and mention ensuring it's on-topic before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/**
     * This method should return whether or not there is an appointment scheduled at
     * any hour of this day.
     *
     * @return true if there is an appointment scheduled during any hour of this
     *         day, false if there are no appointments for this entire day.
     */

```
public boolean checkDay() 
{   

    for(int i = 0; i < isBusy.length; i++)
    {
        if(isBusy[i])
        {
         return true;
        }       
    }
    return false;
}

This method is not correct, see, at the description you said:
```

> return true if there is an appointment scheduled during any hour of this

```
but, when there is no appointment, you return true.



public String toString() {

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    // String is an immutable object. Consider use StringBuilder

      for(int i = 0; i < isBusy.length; i++)
    {
        if(appointmentDescription[i] != null)
        {
            output.append(appointmentDescription[i]);
            if( i < isBusy.length - 1){
             output.append(", ");
             }
             }

    }
    if (output.isEmpty()) {
      return "No appointments scheduled for this entire day";
    } 
     return output.toString();
```

}

This toString method, every iteration you are switching the values.
 If you have all the hours of day as true, you will get only the last appointment of the day.
And, if you have appointments all the day except the last hour, you will get: No appointments scheduled for this entire day